# What is the Identity of the Reals mod $1$?

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to do the first exercise set from Abstract Algebra by
Dummit and Foote.

The question defines 
$$
G=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid0\leq x<1\}
$$

and asks to prove that it is a group with the multiplication: 
$$
x\star y=x+y-\lfloor x+y\rfloor
$$

I have first tried to find the identity: 
$$
x=x\star e=x+e-\lfloor x+e\rfloor
$$

subtracting $x$ from both sides gives 
$$
e=\lfloor x+e\rfloor
$$

where $e,x\in[0,1)$.

How do I solve such an equation ?

I tried guessing for trivial solutions like $0,x,-x$ but that didn't
work. I also thought about proving the existence of such $e$ with
something like the intermediate value theorem (IVT), but if I recall
correctly $\lfloor\rfloor$ is not a continuous function, and being
an Abstract Algebra textbook I suspect that if the solution involves
analysis then it would of been hinted.

Can someone please help me to proceed ? (I prefer a \textbf{hint}
then a solution)

Comment: You rejected a simple answer for no good reason.

Comment: @AndréNicolas - got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: for all $x \in [0,1): \lfloor x \rfloor = 0$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Trivial solutions *do* work.
Note that $(\mathbb R,0)\to (G,\star)$, $x\mapsto x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is a group homomorphism.